# What does kinetic energy at infinity mean in terms of supernovae?

Tags: kinematics, astrophysics, supernova

I have noticed that in some paper that the term "kinetic energy at infinity" is used. I understand what potential energy with reference to infinity mean, but what does the term kinetic energy of ejecta at infinity mean ?

EDIT : Page 27 of this [reference](http://www.google.com.eg/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mpa-garching.mpg.de%2Fmpa%2Fpublications%2Fpreprints%2Fpp2007%2FMPA2101.pdf&ei=ZysfVPTyD8HY7AbVoIDwCg&usg=AFQjCNFNvkG0noSER1Dfa6dqnFVElCk8AQ&sig2=LqVtHFGA4JYbCcsV-j5c_w&bvm=bv.75775273,d.ZGU&cad=rja) and the abstract of this [reference](http://arxiv.org/abs/0910.1590).

Comment: I have not seen this phrase before, can you provide a reference?

Comment: @KyleKanos, please take a look at the edit.
I think it might have something to do with the conversion of internal energy to kinetic energy of the ejecta, so by referring to infinity it might mean the total energy of the ejecta.

Comment: [This source](http://books.google.com/books?id=VlfSviM9eIIC&pg=PA174&lpg=PA174&dq=kinetic+energy+at+infinity+supernova&source=bl&ots=Jr9AQXxjb4&sig=BER3x9x3zf38EmhX5dJR_pLcwJ4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=OC0fVLqvCujhsATV54GYAw&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=kinetic%20energy%20at%20infinity%20supernova&f=false) (Google Book) says *Expansion of the radiation converts internal energy into kinetic energy very far from the source*. So it seems your guess is correct (internal energy to kinetic energy conversion via radiation processes).